# How to install VC++ 2010 Redistributable On Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops

I have hosted my web app on Azure as azure app service. There is an error in the application due to a third-party library. Which says it needs to install VC++ 2010 Redistributable (x64) on the server. how to do that on Azure app service?

Answer (score 1):

In short: you don't. Azure App Service is a PaaS offering, you don't get to decide what gets installed on the machines you run it on. They run within a sandbox that protects your App Service from doing harm (and being harmed). More info on the sandbox can be found here: [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

Apparently some versions of the VC++ Redistributable are already installed on an Azure App Service. Please refer to this article for more info: [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio Azure App Service](https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2017/12/13/visual-c-redistributable-packages-for-visual-studio-azure-app-service/)

An alternative solution would be to run a VM where you can manage the OS and the installed libraries yourself.

Comment: I have run the command using kudu as mentioned in the above article. It gives me below output. I don't know whether the server already has installed those packages?

Comment: Kudu cmd output
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\1926E8D15D0BCE53481466615F760A7F
    ProductName    REG_SZ    Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219
    PackageCode    REG_SZ    D2F20908FE1EAC343B66479416790E40
    Language    REG_DWORD    0x0
    Version    REG_DWORD    0xa009d1b
    Assignment    REG_DWORD    0x1
    AdvertiseFlags    REG_DWORD    0x184
    InstanceType    REG_DWORD    0x0
    AuthorizedLUAApp    REG_DWORD    0x0
    DeploymentFlags    REG_DWORD    0x3
    Clients    REG_MULTI_SZ    :

Comment: I believe the second link should now be:
https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2017/12/13/visual-c-redistributable-packages-for-visual-studio-azure-app-service/

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple Nuget package which contains the 3 DLLs and then added that to my app; it then works as the app looks in the local bin folder first.

Comment: That approach may be handy for something I'm working on. Where are the DLL's installed and what are they called (so I can snag them off my local, which apparently already has the appropriate DLL's installed somewhere)?

Comment: @NicholasWestby Look at my Gist: https://gist.github.com/danpetitt/a85d62ee2ba031dbb242da76f9afa460